# Unable to form elasticsearch cluster in windows

Tags: java, elasticsearch

I want to form a cluster of two nodes in windows with below configurations but i am unble to achieve it.
Here are my elastic yml configuration files

node-1 yml conf details:

```
cluster.name: wincluster
node.name: node-1
network.host: 10.25.214.208
http.port: 9200
node.master: true
node.data: true
discovery.zen.ping.unicast.hosts: ["10.25.214.208", "10.25.214.205:9200"]
discovery.zen.minimum_master_nodes: 1
```

node-2 yml conf details:

```
cluster.name: wincluster
node.name: node-2
network.host: 10.25.214.205
http.port: 9200
node.master: false
node.data: true
discovery.zen.ping.unicast.hosts: ["10.25.214.208:9200", "10.25.214.205"]
discovery.zen.minimum_master_nodes: 1
```

Comment: Remove the `:9200` in the `unicast.hosts` setting. And make sure to start the master node first, wait until it's green and then start the second node.

Comment: when i start my node 2 i am getting this [2017-05-02T16:05:50,651][INFO ][o.e.d.z.ZenDiscovery     ] [node-2] failed to send join request to master [{node-1}{VW5fk65WTw-wBhf0hE2fEQ}{EWrq6F8JQc-32K_OIY3
Ueg}{10.25.214.208}{10.25.214.208:9300}], reason [RemoteTransportException[[node
-2][10.25.214.205:9300][internal:discovery/zen/join]]; nested: ConnectTransportE
xception[[node-1][10.25.214.205:9300] connect_timeout[30s]]; nested: IOException
[Connection timed out: no further information: 10.25.214.205/10.25.214.205:9300]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Working with this config

node-1 yml conf details:

```
cluster.name: wincluster
node.name: node-1
network.host: 10.25.214.208
http.port: 9200
node.master: true
node.data: true
discovery.zen.ping.unicast.hosts: ["10.25.214.208:9300"]
discovery.zen.minimum_master_nodes: 1
```

node-2 yml conf details:

```
cluster.name: wincluster
node.name: node-2
network.host: 10.25.214.205
http.port: 9200
node.master: false
node.data: true
discovery.zen.ping.unicast.hosts: ["10.25.214.208:9300"]
discovery.zen.minimum_master_nodes: 1
```